# Bundle Identifier iphone and ipad versions, can I use the same profile?

Tags: provisioning-profile

I have uploaded an app to the store (still awaiting review) but I did it in iphone only, now I want to upload an ipad version. Question is, do I need to make a new provisioning profile, or will the same one be ok, the app name will remain the same, just changing the images to Ipad version.

Answer (score 2):

If you were releasing a Universal app, you could to it all under one app id.

However, you wont be able to use the same provisioning profile because since it's tied to an app id, which is tied to a bundle identifier.  The bundle identifier and (long) app names must be unique.

So if you have an iPhone app:

Name

```
My Sweet App
```

Bundle identifier

```
com.mysweet.app
```

Your iPad app might need to look something like this:

Name

```
My Sweet App for iPad
```

Bundle identifier

```
com.mysweet.app.ipad
```

Which means you'll need to generate a separate app ID, and consequently a separate provisioning profile.